# library upgrade to .net standard 2.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.1

I have class library written in .net standard 2.0 at visual studio 2017. Now I need to upgrade into .net standard 2.1. The problem is not able to get the .net standard 2.1.

Do I need a visual studio 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [.Net Standard 2.1 represents .NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/net-standard) or higher and [.NET Core 3.0 requires Visual Studio 2019](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0):

Yes, you need Visual Studio 2019 if you want to use Visual Studio to develop a .NET Standard 2.1 - library.